# Sharing huge classifier object among celery tasks

Tags: python, scikit-learn, celery, shared-memory, pickle

I have a pickle object ( classifier ) which is ~200MB. I tried to use static member variable to initialize the object and ran a celery task. Celery created ~8 new processes and each read the object into memory and froze my computer. Is there any shared object solution or any solution to this problem.

I'm trying to classify articles with this object and save it in db as a background task.

EDIT.
Here is the code for my classifier Task

```
from model import Article
import cPickle as pkl
from classifierclasses import Remover, Classifier, ItemSelector, PreProcessor
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost/')

class ClassiferTask(app.Task):
    classifier = pkl.load(open('clf.p', 'rb')) #loading classifier  object initially (huge file)
    def classify(self, article_id, text):
        self.prediction = ClassiferTask.classifier.predict([text])[0]
        Article.update(prediction=self.prediction, is_analyzed=1).where(Article.id == article_id).execute()

    def run(self, id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.classify(id, args[0])
```

when I submit this job to celery, it created new processes and each process trying to read into memory and occupying large memory ~200MB * 8

how can I solve this problem? Is there a better solution to this problem. Is there a celery task that can share a single (read only) object.

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy`'s memory map? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: @mai It's not the soultion. I've edited my question.

Comment: @HariRoshan How did you solve this problem? I am running in to same problem with Django + Heroku +Spacy setup...

Comment: @HariRoshan did you solve this? What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is tricky.

The best approach is probably to store your object in some kind of store and to restructure it to allow read/write to smaller parts of it.

It's impossible to say how to best do this because you provide no details on the object or its interfaces or structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question. I don't think project structure is a problem here. If you want, I can edit it too

Comment: not project structure - data structure. you have a single 200MB object - if you can restructure it so that you can break it down into substructures then you can distribute those between tasks without duplication.

Comment: it's hard to give concrete details because there is no information on the structure or nature of the classifier object. Another possible issue is that your code seems to use object orientation unnecessarily. This is a common issue with Java programmers who start writing python - because Java forces everything to be in a class they do the same in python. However this can actually make things complicated - especially when it comes to concurrent code.

Comment: I think the classifier object is just going to be used to predict, and therefore doesn't need to be mutated. And therefore it could be shared between multiple processes fairly easily to save memory.